# Tower of Hanoi with Constrain (p1->p2 Not allowed, p2->p1 allowed)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to solve variant of tower of hanoi from EPI.

The question is to find minimum number of moves required to move 'n' rings from peg1 to peg2, with constrain that direct transfer of ring from peg1 to peg2 is NOT allowed, while direct transfer of ring from peg2 to peg1 is allowed.

I do some thinking and wrote following code:

```
void findAns(int n, int peg1, int peg2, int peg3)
{
    if(n<1)
        return;
        
    findAns(n-1,peg1,peg2,peg3);
    printf("Move(%d->%d)n",peg1,peg3);
    findAns(n-1,peg2,peg1,peg3);
    printf("Move(%d->%d)n",peg3,peg2);
    
    findAns(n-1,peg1,peg2,peg3);
    
}
```

**I am not sure if my logic has any issue, also i am a bit worried that, this code(or no of moves from this code) is same as if we put constrain that *Each Operation must involve peg3*.**

Can anyone please share their insights about this problem.
I am confused from 2 days in this topic!

Comment: no solution yet!